# Small gaps in between squares using GridView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend

I am hoping to use `GridView.builder` to create a grid of squares. However, one problem that I am having is that sometimes, there is a tiny gap inbetween the rows and columns of the grid. Here is my code and attatched screenshot:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: GridView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            itemCount: _squareColors.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 7,
              mainAxisSpacing: 0.0, // Set mainAxisSpacing to zero
              crossAxisSpacing: 0.0, // Set crossAxisSpacing to zero
            ),
            itemBuilder: ((BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: (() => _changeColor(index)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: _squareColors[index],
                    ),
                    
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[[image: Screenshot: A grid made of gray squares. There are white lines in between certain rows and columns]]

I've tried adjusting the padding and editing some parameters of `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount` but that did not seem to change anything.